# Word wrap macro after 9 characters

Tags: vba

Hi I need to use a barcode reader by writing each read barcode which is composed of nine numbers starting using column A and wrapping each read code.
When I read the codes instead it continues to write on cell A1, not realizing that I have a new code inserted.
Is it possible with a macro, to apply a carriage return to the next line after for example nine numbers read?

````
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
activewoksheet.Target.Value
If Target.Value <> "" Then
Target = Target.Offset(0, 1)
End Sub```
````

Comment: Please, clarify what "which is composed of nine numbers starting using column A" does mean. Doesn't your scaner return in a single cell? The nine numbers are really numbers, returned in 9 cells, or digits of the same barcode, returned in a cell? If this last supposition is your case, you should set the scanner to also send 'Enter' when scans...

Comment: the barcodes I read have nine numbers for example 123456789 234567890
the result is in cell A1 = 123456789234567890
but they are all read in the same cell A1 and each time it reads it continues in the same cell without interruption

Comment: So, read about your scaner how to set it in a way to **also send Enter** after scan... See what type is the scanner and search on internet.  If it does not press Enter, the Change event is not triggered neither, so you cannot do it in this way. But all scanners are able do do it. You must only search for its specific setting.